# Invalid parameter number: Fatal ERROR

Tags: php

```
 /* News Feed Data */
     public function newsFeed()
     {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user.id as id, user.nome as nome, app.id as app_id, app.nome as app_nome, app.descricao as app_descricao, app.like_count as like_count FROM  user , app  WHERE user.id=app.user_id ORDER BY app.id DESC");  
        $stmt->execute();
        //$this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        return $data;
     }

      /* User Reaction Check */
     public function reactionCheck($uid, $msg_id)
     {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT app_like.id , reaction.name from app_like, reaction WHERE reaction.id=app_like.reaction_id AND app_like.user_id=:uid  AND app_like.app_id=:id");  
        /*$stmt->bindValue(':id', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':app_id', $msg_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);*/
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $uid,
                  ':app_id' => $msg_id));
        /*$stmt->execute(array(':id'  => $uid, ':app_id'  => $msg_id));*/
        $this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $data= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        return $data;
     }
```

I´m having problems with Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\xampps\htdocs\review\feed.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampps\htdocs\review\feed.php(29): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampps\htdocs\review\indexa.php(36): feed->reactionCheck('4', '4') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampps\htdocs\review\feed.php on line 29

Comment: I´m facing the same error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in the binding. You have `:uid` in the query but `:id` in the binding.
This should work:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT app_like.id , reaction.name from app_like, reaction WHERE reaction.id=app_like.reaction_id AND app_like.user_id=:uid  AND app_like.app_id=:id");  

    $stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid,
              ':id' => $msg_id));
```